# List of dictionary keys returning too slow?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the .groupby function in pandas and should have around 35k groups. I want to test if a certain value is in the list of group names, so I wrote the logical statement `if x in boxes.groups.keys()` (boxes is what i called my groups) and this statement takes incredibly long to process (over a minute and it didn't even finish before I stopped the code). Is this a bug? Is this happening because there are many groups? Is there another way to test this condition?

Also, when I try to print a list of `boxes.groups.keys()` the code takes incredibly long too, so it seems like retrieving this list is where the time sink is.

Comment: I don't know pandas, but can you do `x in boxes.groups` instead? If it's a normal dict, it would go from O(n) to O(1) time

Comment: What if instead of grouping and checking, just check if the values you want to test are in the column or not?